# Node JSON socket vs protobuf over TCP socket

Tags: json, node.js, sockets, tcp, protocol-buffers

I've been struggling on how to best communicate between two NodeJS processes that might be on different machines.

I have a TCP connection between multiple clients and one server. Those clients will keep the socket open because they will send data permanently and I want to avoid loosing time in opening/closing sockets.

I started using [JSON-Socket](https://github.com/sebastianseilund/node-json-socket) but performances are terrible, so I started modifying it to improve it's performance by different ways:

1. Use int little endian to declare size of the encoded JSON.
2. Buffering messages (individually they are really small ~100 chars per item send) by 64536bytes and then write them to the net socket to avoid sending too many little packets that would cost in networking.
3. When receiving the chunks, I put each individual items in a buffer string and then parse an array of items to avoid loosing time in parsing multiple small ones (cf. [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/json-small-vs-big))
4. Iterate the array of items and trigger an event per item in this array through `process.nextTick(.. socket.emit('item', item) ..)` to avoid call stack errors.

But my feeling is that it's inefficient. So I was thinking about using protobuf to serialize/parse the objects ([Node prtofobuf perf](https://github.com/mafintosh/protocol-buffers#performance)), keep my TCP pipe open to avoid reconnections and still use intLE notation before each item is sent over the wire to parse it and emit it on the other end. But I'm really not sure about the best way to go, or maybe there is event better?

To summarise what I want to achieve:

**X clients** sending items of **~110 chars** long to **1 server**. The server needs to **handle each item individually and acknowledge** that it took each of them into account.

Comment: Protobuf seems like the way to go. Just remember to use some [length prefixing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/length-prefixed-stream) to separate the msg's on the socket. I would recommend you to use [ProtobufJS](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/) library, not any of the other once out there.

Comment: The problem is that the serialisation / parsing is still longer than with JSON from the bench I did. The only one that has better perf is [mafintosh/protocol-buffers](https://github.com/mafintosh/protocol-buffers)

Comment: By longer, you mean more processing time? If that is the main issue, not the wire size you can check out [Cap’n Proto](https://capnproto.org/). If you use some compression (packing they call it) it should be efficient also on wire size.

Comment: I meant that most of my CPU time is waisted in serialising/deserialising JSON which I hate. I went with buffer solutions to avoid serialising and parsing stuff too small but still I'm not happy with that. I don't need to compress at all. For the moment I process around 1MB/s but if I avoid serial/parse I go up to 200MB/s (locally). Cap'n Proto has a weak JS implementation and I'm not sure of how fast it could be.

Comment: Ok, if processing performance is the main issue I would think that making your own solution is the best. If you follow your steps in  1, 2, 3 and 4 there is not much more to add apart from length prefixing.

Have you looked at [Autobahn|JS](http://autobahn.ws/js/index.html)?

Comment: Well basically i did the same than in it's [raw socket transfer portocol](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-js/blob/master/package/lib/transport/rawsocket.js#L310) so I guess I will just need more computing power to make it faster. That's a bit sad that JSON.parse is so slow. I saw also that my BSON serialising before inserting into the DB slows the process down. Thanks for your comments peter!

Comment: I see. Maybe it's better to move to C++ then for the server. Check [these benchmarks](https://github.com/miloyip/nativejson-benchmark). [Here](http://stackify.com/top-11-json-performance-usage-tips/) are some general tricks to make JSON handling faster as well, which you might already know. [Here](https://blog.scottfrees.com/c-processing-from-node-js) is a way to use both node and c++.

Comment: Yeah maybe, need to evaluate that but V8 JSON parser seams to be the fastest anyway. Thanks for your comments!